# frida gives an error "killed" when installing on android

Tags: android, adb

When I try to run Frida server I receive : `j6primelte:/data/local/tmp # ./frida-server`
I get the message of : `"Killed"`
When I tried to google it and search it in the issues I found no suggestions.

I saw in one YouTube video someone doing : `./frida-server &`
Tried it as well and I received output of: `"[1] 19988"`
but I have no idea if it means that is running.

I'm using it on a Samsung J6 device.
Android version : 8.1.
Frida version: frida-server-15.1.12-android-arm.xz

Help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Anyway after it I tried to run the following command: `frida -U -f SOME_APP_PATH -l SOME_SCRIPT_PATH --no-paus`
and I received the output of : `Failed to spawn: need Gadget to attach on jailed Android; its default location is: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local....`

Googled it and it seems that this messages means that my frida-server is not running so I understood that I got to the first step again.

Comment: Apps are not started using a "path", instead you have to use the packageName of the installed APK you want to spawn. Does the command `frida-ps -Ua` work? adb between phone and PC works correctly?

Comment: @Robert
adb is working correctly, the frida-ps -Ua command cannot be run because it is not possible to start the server on the android side. gives the error "killed"

Comment: Try different frida versions, start with latest version (16.1.4) `frida-server-*-android-arm.xz` from here https://github.com/frida/frida/releases